# Attaching mouse events at the window object does not work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

Oh hai, anyone knows why Internet Explorer (8) is not firing events attached to the window?

```
    attachEvent("onmousedown", function(){alert("here")}); //Doesn't work.
    onmouseup = function(){alert("here 2")}; //Guess what? Doesn't work too.
```

Of course, I don't even need to say that this works on Firefox, Opera and Chrome

```
    addEventListener("mousedown", function(){alert("here")}, false)
    onmouseup = function(){alert("here 2")};
```

attachEvent works when on a div or *insert here any DOM element*, but I need the event to be global.

Comment: Have you tried attaching it to the `body`?

Comment: @Adam, oh thanks! I didn't try it to the document object, post it as an answer and I'll chose it as the correct one.

Comment: @Delta Attaching it to the body does work in IE8: `document.body.onmouseup = ...`. You probably just clicked on a part of the viewport that was outside of the BODY element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attaching it to the document

Answer (score 1):

It appears that IE8 (and below presumably) does not bubble mouse events to the `window` object. IE9 seem to have corrected this misbehavior.

**Case 1:** Binding the mouse event at the window object:

```
onmousedown = function() { alert(1); };
```

Works in all current browsers but not in IE8.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/nbtYy/

**Case 2:** Binding the mouse event at the document object:

Works in all current browsers and in IE8.

```
document.onmousedown = function() { alert(1); };
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/nbtYy/2/

Comment: that's because IE8 does not support the window DOM object.

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki `window` is supported by all browsers since the beginning; I’m pretty sure of that.

Comment: You are correct I was confusing it with the addeventlistener()  function...

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching it to the window object like

```
$(window).mouseup(callback)
```